# How to account for empty key values in wp_query?

Tags: wp-query

My goal is to remove posts from my wordpress based home/category pages after they are no longer topical.

I have an 'expire_date' custom field for each post where I enter the date I want them to drop off.

Then (with help from Sally CJ), I use wp_query to filter through the posts and filter out the expired posts:

```
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
    array( // clause/query 1
        'key'     => 'expire_date',
        'value'   => date("Y-m-d"),
        'type'    => 'DATE',
        'compare' => '>=',
    )
);
```

That works great for the posts that have an entry in the 'expire_date' field... however, many posts don't - and apparently they are being filtered out to. They are not included in the results.

So how do I include those posts that don't have an entry?

I read through the wp_query doc and tried this - but the results is that none of the posts are displayed -

```
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
    array( // clause/query 1
        'key'     => 'expire_date',
        'value'   => date("Y-m-d"),
        'type'    => 'DATE',
        'compare' => '>=',
    ),
            
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'expire_date',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    )
            
);
```

clearly I am in over my head :)  Any help appreciated!

Chris

Comment: The `relation` should be in the same level as the two arrays/clauses in your `meta_query` array, i.e. `'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => 'OR', array( 'key' => 'expire_date', ... ), array( 'key' => 'expire_date', ... ) )` :)

Comment: Yea! That's perfect, working completely now, so excited - I've been stuck trying to figure this out for a week. Thank you so much for your help Sally CJ!

Comment: Sally CJ, would you like to copy your comment over as an answer so I can mark it as such and give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I include those posts that don't have an entry?

You can include those posts (which do **not** have the `expire_date` field/meta) by adding a second clause with `'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'`, and then set the `relation` to `OR`:

```php
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
    // the relation between the root clauses/queries; defaults to AND
    'relation' => 'OR',

    array( // root clause/query 1
        'key'     => 'expire_date',
        'value'   => date("Y-m-d"),
        'type'    => 'DATE',
        'compare' => '>=',
    ),

    array( // root clause/query 2
        'key'     => 'expire_date',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
);
```

So actually, you just needed to remove lines 15 and 9 in the code in question.